# Find all the solutions of $z^6 = -4$. Why doesn't $arg(z) = \theta = \arctan \left( \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$ work in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the solutions of $z^6 = -4$.

I want to convert the complex number into polar form, so I do my usual calculations:

$z = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)) = re^{i\theta}$

$|z|$ = 4 = r

And then I try to find $\theta$:

$arg(z) = \theta = \arctan \left( \dfrac{0}{-4} \right)$ Since $y = \sin(\theta) = 0$ and $x = \cos(\theta) = -4$.

But $\arctan \left( \dfrac{0}{-4} \right) = 0$? The solution says that $\theta = \pi$; which makes sense, since $-4$ represents the negative x-axis $= \pi$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain why doesn't the formula $arg(z) = \theta = \arctan \left( \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$ work in this case.

Comment: Remember that $\arg$ is not really $\arctan$. You need to adjust by $\pm \pi$ to get the correct $\arg$, the need of which you have demonstrated here.

Comment: @ZainPatel I see. Can you please elaborate on "$\arctan$ is not really arg"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computation

Comment: @Winther Thanks. This seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$-4=4e^{i(2k+1)\pi} =\rho^6e^{6i\theta}$$

thus

$$\rho=4^\frac 16$$
$$arg (z_k)=\theta_k=\frac {2k+1}{6}\pi $$

$$k=0,1,2,3,4,5$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't really asking about the solution; rather, the behaviour of $\arctan$ with regards to arg$(z)$. Nonetheless, I will accept your answer once I've finished calculating the solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is that you do *not* have to solve for the equation $\tan\theta=\dfrac yx$, but for the *system* of trigonometric equations:
\begin{cases}\cos\theta=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\\
\sin\theta=\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.\end{cases}
This system *implies* the equation, but is *not* equivalent to it. The equation is only a simplified way to find the value of $\theta$. Thus all you can say is
$$\theta\equiv\arctan \frac yx \mod \pi.$$
In the present case, as $x< 0$, $\cos\theta<0$, so $\dfrac\pi2<\theta\le\pi\pmod{2\pi}$, whence the value $\pi$, not $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Winther's comment clarified this concept. I think I understand now.